# How to use javascript (filter) to count the frequency of an object value?

Tags: javascript

This is the [url](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments) from which i have to fetch data.I want the frequency of the postIds.How can i do this using the methods (map,filter or reduce).I've done it using a loop .Can it be done in a better way?.please help..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
  fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) 
      {
          var na=[];
          for(var i=1;i<=100;i++)
          {
            var a= data.filter(ab=> {
          return ab.postId==i;});
         // console.log(a); 
          na.push({PostId:i,frequency:a.length});
          }
          console.log(na);
      }
  )})
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note the answers given only iterate the array once whereas using `filter()` to create a new array to get it's length iterates the array once for every item in it

Comment: @-charlietfl thank you...i knew there must be a better way to do this..what i was doing was similar to using a nested loop..

Comment: Right...plus each returned filter array takes up needless memory until it gets garbage collected

Comment: @charlietfl yeah ..first i thought of emptying the array with a=[] but i knew i had to post it as a question so i shouldn't optimize a wrong approach lol..and i used a predefined length as well which was also wrong..thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to generate a map of `PostId` with its frequency.

```
function mapFrequency(data) {
     return data.reduce((map, datum) => {
        if (map[datum.postId]) {
          map[datum.postId] += 1;
        } else {
          map[datum.postId] = 1 
        }
        return map;
        
     }, {})
}
```

This function will create an object with keys as `postId` and value as its frequency.

If you want to generate an array as in your sample, you can then do

```
 const frequencies = mapFrequency(data);
 const result = Object.keys(frequencies).map((id) => {
   return {
      PostId: id, 
      frequency: frequencies[id]
   }
  });
```

Comment: Thank You for your help : )

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps

```js
let counterObj = {};

let cars = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2015' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Mercedes', year: '2000' },
    { id: 3, name: 'BMW', year: '2010' },
    { id: 4, name: 'BMW', year: '2004' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Volvo', year: '2012' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Volvo', year: '2014' } 
];


for (let item of cars){
    counterObj[item.name] = 1 + (counterObj[item.name] || 0)
}

console.log(counterObj);
```

Comment: I have to solve it with reduce,map or filter and nothing else.Thank you for answering but i want a solution that uses these methods only.

Answer (score 1):

With reduce you can do something like this:

```js
const na = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.postId] = acc[el.postId] ? acc[el.postId] + 1 : 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Pretty much the same as @sonEtLumiere suggested, but with `reduce`

Comment: thank you..this is how i wanted ..I just wanted to know that can I use map on your answer to get the result in the form of {postId: postIdNumber,frequency: frequencyOfPostId}?